# Set up Windows Server VPN programatically

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, vpn, windows-server-2022

How to migrate VPN server user from Windows Server 2016 to 2022 programmatically/automatically?
On Windows Server 2016 is the build-in Windows VPN used.

Details: Users can connect to a server A running Windows Server 2016. What to do so they can connect to new/fresh Virtual Private Server B running Windows Server 2022? Ideally with the same login and password.

I prefer to create the new VPN by C# or PowerShell.

To the fresh Windows Server 2022 the RRAS feature can be added by PowerShell script (are all needed for VPN server only?):

```
Install-WindowsFeature RemoteAccess
Install-WindowsFeature DirectAccess-VPN -IncludeManagementTool
Install-WindowsFeature Routing -IncludeManagementTools
```

Then probably it's needed to create users. Probably like this:

```
net user
```

I can also find how to create VPN connection on the client via

```
Add-VpnConnection
```

But I assume that's not all. What to do on the server so the users can connect to it via VPN?

Comment: Part of the answer can be https://akyriako.medium.com/install-the-routing-and-remote-access-server-rras-on-windows-server-2022-8b0c2d880507 and script: Install-WindowsFeature RemoteAccessInstall-WindowsFeature DirectAccess-VPN -IncludeManagementToolInstall-WindowsFeature Routing -IncludeManagementTools

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What file do you mean for your last question? Please note that SuperUser requires a single question per post, in order that a single answer can be marked correct. Multiple posts is OK, so long as your account is in good standing. What research have you done regarding this? Windows Server has documented methods of automating or scripting configurations, namely PowerShell, SCCM/MECM, Intune, and Group Policy. Are you trying to migrate an existing VPN host from 2016 to 2022? Please add context and detail, including what you have tried so far.

Comment: Question edited. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @TomasTintera Everything you need PowerShell command wise should be listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/remoteaccess/?view=windowsserver2022-ps for Server 2022 and RA module, etc. Basically though, get one to work doing it manually and ensure the steps are documented once you figure out the manual configs to all VPN access. Then you figure out and research how to do each step with PowerShell one-by-one if possible. That's how I'd go about it but it might take some trial and error.... Good luck!!

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Added follow up question.